# Roku Sliding Panel

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am using sliding panel in my project. Suppose I have panel A (on left) and B(on right) in a panel set. Now I slide to panel C from B and now my panel set has panel B and C. Similarly I keep on going level deep such that now panel set has panel E(on left) and F(on right).

Now I want that my panel set to slide and show the initial panel A and B directly once I do some action(say by pressing a button present on panel F).

How can this be achieved? It's similar behavior as you see on Roku home screen. For eg: If I am on Roku caption style setting and I press the home button, the screen slides back to the home page listing and animate to Home option irrespective of how many panels were present in between.
I tried goBackCount property of the panel but to no avail. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

After setting goBackCount to value greater than 1 try to call onKeyEvent() function and pass "key" and "press" arguments like this: `onKeyEvent("left", true)`. If I understood Roku docs correctly, goBackCount works only after and if "left" remote key is pressed.

Comment: the function on key gets called but the focus does not go to previous screen even when return is set to false. Also. goBackCount property is not working anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using Roku Tasks and ECP(External Control API).
First I created a task to do the ECP calls to press a remote button.
RemoteControlTask.xml:

```
<component name = "RemoteControlTask" extends = "Task" >

<interface>
    <field id = "url" type = "string" />
    <field id = "content" type = "node" />
</interface>
<script type = "text/brightscript" >

<![CDATA[

    sub init()
        m.deviceIP = GetDeviceIP()
        m.top.functionName = "SlideLeft"
    end sub

    function PressKey(key as String)
        request = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
        request.SetRequest("POST")
        port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
        request.SetMessagePort(port)
        url = "http://" + m.deviceIP + ":8060/keypress/" + key
        request.SetUrl(url)
        if(request.AsyncGetToString())
            while(true)
                msg = wait(0, port)
                if(type(msg) = "roUrlEvent")
                    code = msg.GetResponseCode()
                    if(code = 200)                   
                        return true
                    else
                        print code
                    end if
                else if(event = invalid)
                    request.AsyncCancel()
                end if
            end while
        end if
        return invalid
    end function

    function SlideLeft()
        PressKey("left")
    end function

    function GetDeviceIP() as String
        device = CreateObject("roDeviceInfo")
        deviceIP = device.GetIPAddrs()["eth1"]
        return deviceIP
    end function
]]>


</script>


</component>
```

Then, in the script that will trigger the scroll back, add the following to the init() method:

```
m.remoteControlTask = CreateObject("roSGNode", "RemoteControlTask")
```

And add the subroutine:

```
sub RunRemoteControlTask()
    m.remoteControlTask.control = "RUN"
end sub
```

Lastly, call RunRemoteControlTask when the button is pressed:

```
RunRemoteControlTask()
```